# I changed my OS from windows 11 to Ubuntu and now I have no free disk space

Tags: disk, disk-management

I just changed my OS from Windows11 to Ubuntu22.04 LTS but the problem is that when I was installed Ubuntu I noticed I didn't have much free disk space left although my disk capacity is 1TB. I don't know a lot about partitions so I installed Ubuntu in the default way but I checked the partitions before doing it and I only had like 14400MB or so. I don't know what to do,I'm not used to Ubuntu but I want to learn because I want to learn coding, I hope someone can help me and thank you all in advance :) Have a nice day.
Here is a pic of my laptop specs: [laptopspecs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdD8F.png)
Here is another one of my disk usage analyzer: [diskanalyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yul7y.png)
And finally another one of my console with df command output:[dfoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyQWt.png)

PD: Sorry for any grammar mistakes, english is not my native language :) have a good day all of you!

Edit1: I tried to install gparted but I got this error: [gPartedError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9nrS.png)
When I clicked "cancel" I got this: [gParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQnSa.png)
And here is the output of fdisk -l: [fdisk1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knK9A.png)[fdisk2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXnxM.png)

Edit2: I solved the problem, thank you all for your help! As some of you told me I actually had both windows and ubuntu installed, and windows was using most of my storage. I ended up downloading a new windows ISO and using it to boot and delete those partitions since they won't appear in ubuntu boot. Then I just reinstalled ubuntu in the 1TB drive :) since I don't know much about partitions I didn't noticed my laptop had an NVMe and I thought it was just another partition! Thank you again all of you kind strangers, I hope you all have a nice day:)

Comment: Show us the output of `sudo fdisk -l` on the command line, or install `gparted` and show us the screenshot of what it shows.

Comment: Hello @ThomasWard I just edited the post adding the info you ask:) Thank you for you help!

Comment: according to your fdisk your nvme drive is only 14GB large.  Are you sure you have a larger NVMe than that?  If you do then your system did not install or partition correctly the NVMe

Comment: I'm sure my hard disk is 1TB, I don't know what NVMe means :( I've been using this laptop before with windows and never had storage issues, maybe I installed ubuntu wrong?

Comment: You did not change your OS you made a dualboot with windows,

Comment: Hi @nobody, that is what I was thinking! do you know how I can fix it? I can't boot windows anymore

Comment: Your `fdisk` output shows that you have two drives. One is `/dev/nvme0n1` which has only 14 GB and Linux is installed there, and you have another drive `/dev/sda` which is nearly 1 TB and is fully used by Windows, it has Windows partitions on it. You say that you had only one 1 TB drive. What is the first drive (where Ubuntu is installed) then? You installed Ubuntu on the wrong drive. You should have it installed on the 1 TB drive with Windows still on it.

Comment: This is an issue that may be similar to yours: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/u5ygkc/my_laptops_nvme_drive_shows_up_as_2_separate/ . There is probably actually a "hidden" NVMe drive in your laptop. So I guess you should reinstall Ubuntu and explicitly tell the installer to use `/dev/sda` drive for installation and not `/dev/nvme0n1`.

Comment: Search for more links: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=one+hard+drive+shows+as+two&t=ffsb&ia=web - the issue appears for people who are using Windows as well.

Comment: It is hard to read but you show "Backup gpt partition table is not at end of drive". I might try fixing that first. `sudo gdisk /dev/nvme0n1`
Command (? for help):
To move backup to end of drive
 launch gdisk, then type x, then type e, then type w to save your changes

Comment: @oldfred Regardless of moving the GPT, `/dev/nvme0n1` is still only 14 GB in size, and OP wants Ubuntu installed on the other drive, `/dev/sda`, which is 1 TB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't deplete more storage by using less.

Either you installed Ubuntu **side-by-side** with Windows, or you installed it on a different drive. Needless to say, Windows is almost definitely still installed. If you want to completely wipe your drive, make sure you choose the correct formatting / partitioning options when installing Ubuntu. There should be a clearly labeled "WARNING: This will clear everything on your drive" option (or at least something similar to it) that's going to look really scary, but that's the option you're probably looking for.

**Revision**

For anybody who's unfamiliar with disk partitioning, I think this is going to help out quite a bit. For this, assume that a computer is only using 1 disk drive that has 1 TB of disk space.

A standard Windows installation is going to be approximately 20 GB give or take. A standard Linux installation is going to be approximately 2 GB give or take. (Assuming higher standard.)

Windows is known for using the NTFS file system whereas Linux commonly uses EXT4.

What ends up happening is that a certain byte range is required for certain aspects like the Master Boot Loader (MBR) as well as for Swap space as well as for system recovery options (back ups). I'm not going to delve too deep into the actual details of which the system operates.

My point being that in essence, you cannot put everything altogether and expect it to work. So that's where partitioning comes in - essentially splitting up the drive into regions.

This allows the MBR to be separated from the actual root file system, which also allows it to be formatted using a different file system. Same goes for the recovery options. So if you're to remove the Windows installation, the Windows MBR will still exist. If you remove the Windows MBR but not the Windows installation, you will have Windows, you just won't be able to boot it up.

So when it comes to installing multi-boot systems, such as a dual-boot Windows + Linux system, it will partition the disk so that a certain amount of space is allocated for Windows in NTFS and a certain amount of space is allocated for Linux in EXT4.

Distribution installers should offer an ability to completely wipe the drive and install which should work by first formatting the drive completely and removing existing partitions. This allows for the proper creation of partitions for the new file system so long as it's properly configured to consume the entire byte range of the drive.

Now, where this may become a problem...

With multiple drives in a system, this option will only wipe and partition 1 drive. Meaning if you have your MBR or file system on another drive, they will remain as such. This can confuse the BIOS on boot, and will likely give you the option to boot onto this non-existing operating system or vice versa; which leaves you with a malfunctioning or bloated system.

So if you truly want to wipe everything and install from scratch, you need to format all drives.

If you would like to check your partitions, in Windows you can use the Disk Management tool that's built-in, and on Linux you can either use the `fdisk` CLI tool or GParted GUI tool. Make sure to check each drive. This should give you some idea of how your system is handling partitions, and should also give you the option to reformat certain partitions, remove certain partitions, or reallocate the amount of space on the selected partition if you have a lot of unused space on the drive.

Bear in mind, reformatting will **COMPLETELY** wipe the drive. The only way to recover data after a reformat is to use special recovery tools, and it only works partially. Any new file writes in the old sectors will corrupt the old data making it completely irrecoverable, but should have no effect on the new data.

Comment: Hi Ty Q! I agree with you that windows is almost definitely still in  my computer. The problem is that when I was installing Ubuntu I got that WARNING message and installed it. I actually did it twice because I was convinced there was some sort of mistake. I even checked the partitions from the "more options" option during installation I didn't find any partition with windows or NTFS. Do you have any ideas of what else can I do?

Comment: @ErickSandoval Yeah just boot up GParted and check all your drives for a Windows installation. In essence, if there's just a lot of "Free Space" you need to fix your Ubuntu partition during install to include 100% of it rather than just a small portion. You should also be able to just resize / reallocate the amount on your partition in GParted.